# Fail Files that have no value stored using JSON Schema file

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, jsonschema

I have code that validates .json files using a schema file.
I'm trying to validate a list of values.
But if the file has a "NO_DATA", "EMPTY", or "NULL" stored as a value, I want
`Splunk_Status = Data_JSON.IsValid(Schema)` to be false.

Schema file I have so far:

```json
"MN": {
    "Type": "string",
    "pattern": "[A-Z0-9]{14}",
},
```

File to fail:

```json
{
  "MN": "NO_DATA",
}
```

File to pass (It doesn't have to have the exact pattern it just needs to not be empty):

```json
{
"MN": "FS40-SR20D4-2C00W",
}
```

VB.net code:

```vb
schemaConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("LOCAL_SPLUNK_SCHEMA_PATH")
schema_path = schemaConn.ToString
            Schema_String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(schema_path)
extra_str = backup_path
Schema = JsonSchema.Parse(Schema_String)
step_str = "Validate JSON File Data Using Schema"
Data_String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Splunk_Info.FullName)
Data_JSON = JObject.Parse(Data_String)
Splunk_Status = Data_JSON.IsValid(Schema)
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
Console.WriteLine("SPLUNK VALIDATE: " + Splunk_Status.ToString)
If Splunk_Status = True Then
    File_Validation = True
    Console.WriteLine("File Location = " + Splunk_Info.FullName)
    GoTo Jump_ValidateHeader
Else
    File_Validation = False
    GoTo Jump_ValidateHeader
End If
```

Comment: `I have code that validates .json files using a schema file.` If you want a vb.net answer, it would be helpful to post at least some vb.net

Comment: I updated my post with my code.

Comment: Code isn't really necessary here as this is a JSON Schema problem, which transcends implementation language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prohibit certain values by combining the `not` and `enum` keywords:

```
"not": {
  "enum": [ "NO_DATA", "EMPTY", "NULL" ]
}
```

You can read about these keywords here:

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#id4
- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#id8